# What is the rationale behind using an union in DECLARE_KFIFO

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, unions

I am looking at the `<linux/kfifo.h>`, specifically the [DECLARE_KFIFO](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/include/linux/kfifo.h#L101) macro, and I can't figure out why use an `union`.

```
#define DECLARE_KFIFO(name, size) \
union { \
    struct kfifo name; \
    unsigned char name##kfifo_buffer[size + sizeof(struct kfifo)]; \
}
```

My questions are as follows:

1. What is the point of using an `union` over here ? **What design goal does that solve ?** Is it for performance reasons ?
2. How would you even access this anonymous union ? For example this does not work:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
   union {
       int a;
       float b;
   };

   a = 10;
   }
   main.c:18:5: error: ‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   a = 10;
   ^
   ```

**Why declare something that cannot be used ?**

3. How does this work with the [INIT_KFIFO](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.33/source/include/linux/kfifo.h#L87) macro ? How is able to access the union and what relation does it have with the previous macro ?
4. If my memory serves me correctly, then in C you can only use one one element in an union. So what is going on here ? **It will just use one member from the declared union ?**

*Note: This code is for the 2.6.33 kernel. I know its old code, but the recent kernel [5.6.12](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.12/source/include/linux/kfifo.h#L52) still uses a union in kfifo, only its a lot more complicated.*

Comment: Note that this implementation of the kfifo API was never actually used in practice. If you take a look at the rest of kernel code, nothing used `DECLARE_KFIFO` before it was changed to the current version that is not using an `union`, but a `struct` (as @Tsyvarev explains below). As for why it was declared as an `union` in the first place, you would have to ask the original author ([Stefani Seibold](https://seibold.net/)) directly. It almost looks more like a mistake rather than a meaningful design choice.

Answer (score 1):

The comments to the macro explain *almost* everything:

```
/**
 * DECLARE_KFIFO - macro to declare a kfifo and the associated buffer
 * @name: name of the declared kfifo datatype
 * @size: size of the fifo buffer. Must be a power of two.
 *
 * Note1: the macro can be used inside struct or union declaration
 * Note2: the macro creates two objects:
 *  A kfifo object with the given name and a buffer for the kfifo
 *  object named name##kfifo_buffer
 */
```

This macro is used **only** as a (some other) structure's or union's **field**. With such usage the macro creates(allocates in the structure or in the union):

- a kfifo object which can be accessed as a field with the name `name` and
- a buffer for kfifo.

So, structure declaration like

```
struct my_struct {
   int a;
   char b;
   DECLARE_KFIFO(my_fifo, 100);
};
```

gives similar effect as

```
struct my_struct {
   int a;
   char b;
   // This field may be used for call kfifo functions
   struct kfifo my_fifo;
   // This field is never used directly.
   // Pointer to this buffer is stored in the '.buffer' field of kfifo object.
   unsigned char buffer_internal_to_kfifo_implementation[size];
};
```

It would be more natural for declaring two objects to use a anonymous **structure** of two fields instead of *union*:

```
#define DECLARE_KFIFO(name, size) \
struct { \
    struct kfifo name; \
    unsigned char name##kfifo_buffer[size]; \
}
```

It should be exactly anonymous for allow direct access to its `name` field.

Compared to structure's implementation, actual implementation of `DECLARE_KFIFO` via anonymous **union** gives the same "field" `name` and allocates the same amount of bytes (of number `size`) for its buffer:

```
union { \
    struct kfifo name; \
    unsigned char name##kfifo_buffer[size + sizeof(struct kfifo)]; \
}
```

It is difficult to say why they choose `union` instead of `struct`.

---

> the recent kernel 5.6.12 still uses a union in kfifo, only its a lot more complicated.

Not quite true. The newer kernel versions uses `union` for absolutely different purposes:

```
#define __STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON(datatype, recsize, ptrtype) \
    union { \
        struct __kfifo  kfifo; \
        datatype    *type; \
        const datatype  *const_type; \
        char        (*rectype)[recsize]; \
        ptrtype     *ptr; \
        ptrtype const   *ptr_const; \
    }
```

Here `kfifo` is the only field which is accessed for write/read bytes of data. All other fields are declared just for extract their **types** using `typeof()` operator.

So, `__STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON` is just a "clever" `struct kfifo` declaration which knows types of data it contains.

Definition of `DECLARE_KFIFO` macro

```
#define DECLARE_KFIFO(fifo, type, size) STRUCT_KFIFO(type, size) fifo
```

after expanding intermediate macros gives:

```
#define DECLARE_KFIFO(fifo, type, size) struct { \
    __STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON(type, recsize, ptrtype); \
    type        buf[((size < 2) || (size & (size - 1))) ? -1 : size]; \
} fifo
```

So that time it is a field of the structure type with the given name. Similar to the old definition, this structure contain two fields:

- `struct kfifo` object (its "clever" version) and
- a buffer for kfifo.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `__STRUCT_KFIFO_COMMON` is a "clever" `struct kfifo` declaration. **Am I correct when I say that in a union only 1 member can be accessed at a time ?** If so if I access `struct __kfifo` then where does the datatype information go to ? because it seems it would become inaccessible if I do that. also vice-versa, if I access the datatype the data is lost.

Comment: "in a union only 1 member can be accessed at a time ?" - No, C language doesn't have such restriction. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-and-undefined-behavior. Note, that in a union members share only **data**. So a **type** of a union's member is never lost.